# How to calculate the expectancy of the ratio of non-independent random variables?

Tags: random-variable, expected-value, independence

How can I calculate this expectancy:
$$
E \left [  \frac{\sum_{t=1}^T{Z_tX_t}}{\sum_{t=1}^T{Z_t^2}} \right ]
$$
where $Z_t \sim N(0,1)$ and $X_t \sim N(0,1)$ are independent? Any tricks? Is it possible?

Comment: By symmetry, it's either zero or undefined.  Factor the vector $(Z_t)$ into a chi variable times one that is uniformly distributed on the sphere to demonstrate the expectation is defined.

Comment: @whuber. Thanks, but I don't understand. $\sum_{t=1}^T Z_t^2 = Y_t \sim \chi^2(T)$ sure (by definition), but $Y_t$ and $Z_t$ are still not independent, so I can't drag the expectancy in the fraction. What do you mean by symmetry?

Comment: Symmetry: the distribution of $X_t$ and the distribution of $-X_t$ are identical.  You don't need to assume independence to apply this.

Comment: How can symmetry be used here? Could you please give a short sketch of the proof?

Comment: I already did.  Writing $R$ for the fraction, symmetry implies $E[R]=-E[R].$ Once you show the expectation is defined and finite, all you have to do is solve the equation $x=-x$ ;-).

Comment: Oh that simple, thanks. Then there remains the questions 1) how to show that $R$ is symmetric and 2) how to show that the expectancy is defined. I don't really understand the chi square times uniform idea. Do you have a link/source where that solution path is used?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=sphere+normal+uniform.